# Can browsers automaticly change the attribute src of iframe?

Tags: html, apache, iframe

I met a strange problem. Here is the HTML fragment:

```
<iframe src="http://XXXXX/x?_t=XX&_crid=D-123-123&_pr=http%3A%2F%2Fy0%2Ebai.htm"></iframe>
```

but, when I opened the apache access_log, I found some strange requests, the request should be:

> GET `/x?_t=XX&_crid=D-123-123&_pr=http%3A%2F%2Fy0%2Ebai.htm http/1.1`

but has become:

> GET `/x?_t=XX&_crid=d-123-123&_pr=http%3a%2f%2fy0%2ebai.htm http/1.1`

all of the capital letters were changed to be lowercase letters.
Is there anybody that has met this case before, and can anybody explain it?

Comment: There is not much in here to investigate, but I guess you could have a `RewriteMap` that made everything lowercase.

Comment: Thank your help, but we absolute confirm that we don`t RewiteMap.

Comment: I just noticed I have read this wrong. As you said it's the access log that have the lower case characters and afaik that is before any processing has been done by Apache. I need to read up on when the access log is written. Is it the same with different browsers?

Comment: Your answer is so quickly. I`m sorry my comment is so late.According to the UA,record by apache, it is same with different browser. Ipad, IE, chrome, I`m wording ... This situation dose not allways happen. All of these logs record with null reffer. Could I confirm it`s caused by web spider??

Comment: No worries, answer when you have time. What is web spider? I guess if you really want to confirm what you get it's the access log or sniffing the port on the Apache server computer. Hence what you have in your access log should be the request Apache receive, and before any manipulation has been done by Apache itself.

Comment: well, webspider is used by Search Engine to access webpage, or some information.Maybe we called it webspider,you don`t. It`s more like a spider in the web, jumps from one page to another. You mean access log is the first and the root, and apache will not change true request?

Comment: The access log show the request as is specified by `LogFormat` (in your configuration file). The data in there is what Apache receive, and before Apache itself has processed it. Hence, unless your browser sends the request as shown someone on the path between browser and Apache must have altered it.